# Using $CamelCase for object instances and $lower_case for everything else

Tags: php, variables, naming-conventions

Here's a simple convention for naming variables:

> Use $CamelCase for object instances
>   and "$lower_case" for everything else.

Can you think of a reason not to use it?

I came up with this convention a few months ago and I've been using it in a few small projects since then. I'm about to start using it in a big project so I want to be sure I'm not missing something.

Comment: What I cannot think is a reason to post this question.

Comment: "You've reached the maximum of 12 Closure votes per day; come back in 2 hours" - for the record I find this too subjective for this site. Try Programmers.SE.

Comment: @manuelpedrera, I added a paragraph in attempt to explain the reason behind posting the question.

Comment: @tchrist, you have a good point there but I'm not sure if you take into consideration that most object instance names consist of a single word and rarely more than two words.

Comment: @tchrist, could you please edit your comment to make the name example shorter so it doesn't break the layout of the page? I get the point.

Comment: YouMeanSomeReasonOtherThanHowCamelCaseChucksLegibiltyOutTheWindow?

Comment: @tchrist: Actually I found your comment fairly easy to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use whatever naming convention that suites you best, as long as the project will only ever be developed on by you.

The reason we have standards is that when developers collaborate together on a project, there already used to the syntax and the naming conventions as the what we call the *standard*.

As your specifically *coding* in PHP then i would advise you to use a well known naming convention such as Zend or PEAR.

There is no reason what so ever to come up with a new naming convention unless all your programmers or people that work on the code all opt in for this and its thought out properly.

Some Conventions:

- http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php
- http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html

I Personally prefer Zend over PEAR but the above to are the most popular when it comes down to standards.

Edit: Some examples of the conventions i use.

- Global Variables `$MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE`
- Generic Variables `$lowerUpper`
- Class Names `Upper_For_Each_Segment`
- Class Variables `$this->lowerUpper`
- Class variables Private / Protected `$this->_lowerUpper`
- Constants `ALL_UPPER_CASE`

You can modify the convention slightly to fit your requirements but its best to stick to the most popular convention at the time.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your own conventions!

Answer (score 1):

Usually one follows this age-old rules triple:

- Use `$ALL_CAPS` for nominal constants.
- Use `$Each_Word_Capped`  for global variables.
- Use `$no_words_capped` for local variables.

Notice how with this scheme, you *always* separate words with underscores: underscores serves as space characters to guide the eye. This is more valuable than you realize. This is a **perfectly consistent** rule, and much more readable than most alternatives. Try remove the spaces in this posting to see what I mean.

Comment: I should add that the Go programming language puts this into practice: capped stuff is public, lowercase is private.